# wikidata get number of deaths (P1120)and associated time of COVID-19 pandemic (Q81068910)

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to get 2019–20 COVID-19 pandemic (Q81068910) number of deaths (P1120)+ associated time for each country.
I use the wikidata sparql as following, I cannot get the associated time of number of deaths (P1120).
I try to add  ?num wdt:P585 ?time in the following sparql, but I get an error.
Thank you for your help.

SELECT ?pandemic ?pandemicLabel ?num ?time ?country  ?countryLabel
WHERE 
{
  ?pandemic wdt:P31  wd:Q3241045.
  ?pandemic wdt:P361  wd:Q81068910.
  ?pandemic wdt:P1120 ?num.
  #?num wdt:P585 ?time #error, mark it as comment
  ?pandemic wdt:P17 ?country.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}

Comment: that's not how the Wikidata model works. I mean, ?num would be a number which can't be the subject of an RDF triple. Please read about "statement qualifiers" of the Wikidata model.

Comment: That said: `SELECT ?pandemic ?pandemicLabel ?num ?time ?country ?countryLabel {
  ?pandemic wdt:P31 wd:Q3241045.
  ?pandemic wdt:P361 wd:Q81068910.
  ?pandemic p:P1120 [ ps:P1120 ?num ; pq:P585 ?time ] .
  ?pandemic wdt:P17 ?country.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}`